# Adding new operations in Tensorflow using an approach different from tutorial

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Here is a tutorial about [how to add a new operation in TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html). It talks about how to create a shared object and load it in python.

However, there are some operations, which located in core/kernels, didn't generate shared object. Instead, TF will generate files like `gen_some_ops.py` in `dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops`.

If I want to use the second approach to add a new operation (say `zero_out`), then what should I do (in addition to the tutorial)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The core operators are in `_pywrap_tensorflow.so`. If you plan on contributing to the core, that's where they would go. Typically, though, we would first accept them into the `contrib` directory, then at a later stage move into the core. It's best to file a [github issue](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) before you start working to coordinate with us.

If you're not planning on contributing back, then the `user_ops` path is the most appropriate. That way you can have some level of version-independence.

Comment: I am currently doing a project which changes the implementation of an operation of TF. So I will work on the core module. I didn't figure out how operations are linked to `_pywrap_tensorflow.so` as I didn't find related string in `core/BUILD`. Should I look for somewhere else?

Comment: That's the `tf_py_wrap_cc` rule for `tensorflow/python:pywrap_tensorflow`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I somehow missed this file when I use `grep`.